# Moving Average for python issue

Tags: python, time-series, pandas-groupby, moving-average, rolling-computation

I am looking at corona data from the NY Times which can be found here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-counties.csv

And open for everyone to use.

The dataset is set up like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-counties.csv')
df2 = df.copy()
df2 = df2.set_index('date')
df2['cases_lagged'] = df2.groupby(['county', 'state'])['cases'].shift()
df2[df2['fips']== 34041.0].head(10)
```

I was hoping I could create a moving average column the same way using a groupby statement along with the .rolling() command from pandas to compile a 7-day and 14-day moving average for the data but it does not work.

I tried it two separate ways:

```
#way 1
df2['moving_avg'] = df2.groupby(['county', 'state']).iloc[:4].rolling(window = 7).mean()

#way 2
df2['moving_avg'] = df2.groupby(['county', 'state'])['cases'].rolling(window = 7).mean()
```

And neither seems to work here.

Any thoughts on how to compile the moving average for each county within each state without having to break out each and every county into its own df for it to work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When I ran it with all data, I terminated it because it was running for a long time. We limited the run to specific counties.
I'm not sure I think I've achieved the intended result.

```
los = df2[(df2['county'] == 'Los Angeles') & (df2['state'] == 'California')]
los['moving_avg'] = los[['county', 'state', 'cases']].groupby(['county', 'state'], group_keys=False).rolling(window = 7).mean()
```

Comment: I mean the problem is that if we only use it for one county I would just do

df.iloc[:,4].rolling(window = 14)

The problem is how to account for each county in the data

Comment: You may not yet understand the intent of the question, but you can do a loop process with a unique list of counties and states.
I wonder if it is possible to take out the unique groups and states below.
`df2[~df2.duplicated(['county','state'])].loc[:,['county','state']]`